# How to solve for translation only between two cameras given rotation matrix?

Tags: opencv, computer-vision

Given 100 keypoint matches between two images, assuming we know the orientation of the cameras from which these images are generated, can we accurately solve for translation between cameras? if yes, how?

Comment: Do you mean having 2D keypoint matches? as in SIFT or similar?

Comment: Yes, like SIFT, I have detected keypoints using some feature detector and obtained matches.